# Possible location of impact injury?

Tags: plot, brainstorming

It is essential to the plot of my story for My character (human) to be injured. I know her injuries which are, her leg and right arm bones are either fractured or broken in different places. Her right shoulder is dislocated. On her left arm, her fingers and hand are broken as well as her wrist and her elbow is dislocated. 3 ribs broke on her right side and there is one rib dislocation. Other than huge scrapes and a concussion and gash on the head. Her right side is the most beat up but her left still has significant injuries. These injuries are impact injuries. What I am having trouble is what caused it? It has to look almost suicidal.

So maybe hit by a train? At what speed, is my character in a vehicle? Did the force of the train push her out?

Did my character fall somewhere in the Grand Canyon ( they are in Arizona) Did my character just fall into the river or on the stone? was there anything blocking her fall, like foliage?

Did she fall from a building onto cement? was there a tree blocking her path? Did she hit a balcony or something first? At what height?

From a bridge in Arizona? At what height? did she hit something underwater? Was she pulled downstream?

What is the most logical way to obtain her injuries? What other ways could she have been injured?

Comment: Did you consider asking a medical doctor about this?

Comment: yes I have considered talking to a doctor that is how I came up with injuries all can be caused by impact trauma and are mainly non-fatal

Comment: This question seems more about plot brainstorming than about writing.

Comment: This is off-topic. Perhaps you should ask on worldbuilding instead, or maybe the mods could migrate it.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe this would be off topic on [worldbuilding.se] too, I believe.

Comment: The [tag:brainstorming] tag says not to use it for brainstorming…. It's a little counter-intuitive.

Comment: I have tried worldbuilding writing, biology, all of the stack exchanges. Maybe I will propose a new stack exchange.

Answer (score 4):

## Being hit by a truck would be a plausible cause for those injuries

Now this is a morbid question. I really hope you're not asking us to provide you with an alibi to tell to the police... ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

**She is wandering on a highway at night** ("It has to look almost suicidal").

- Why? Some kids do this kind of stuff for dares. Maybe she was drunk, or had been drugged.
- Maybe she was actually suicidal: men attempt suicide less often, but with fast-acting methods (hanging, firearms), while women attempt suicide more often, with [slow-acting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_differences_in_suicide#Differing_methods_by_gender) methods that are more likely to be countered (drug overdose).
- As such, an attempt at a suicide on the highway is plausible: it is quite possible that someone will catch her, stop, and try to talk to her; or at least, that's what she thinks in her mind.

**A truck hits the right side of her body, she is sent flying** ("Her right side is the most beat up").

- A truck, [specifically the tractor](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-m7VR7vxNgCo/TscIS_Z2TUI/AAAAAAAAATA/Sf54POGc1M0/s1600/HOWO+6x2+tractor.JPG), is tall enough to reach her shoulder ("Her right shoulder is dislocated").
- Also, it provides a truckload (pun intended) of kinetic energy that sends her flying.
- When she lands, either:

  - Her body lands over her arm, which then takes the brunt of the impact, resulting in the injuries you described; or
  - The driver does't manage to brake on time, and runs over her left arm and leg ("her fingers and hand are broken as well as her wrist and her elbow is dislocated").
  - I think the second alternative is more plausible, especially if this happens at night time. The driver was tired and sleepy, didn't notice her, and doesn't try to brake or steer to avoid the impact.

**She hits her head on the pavement**.

- This causes "[A] concussion and gash on the head".

**The force of the impact drags her across the road**.

- This causes the cuts across her body ("Huge scrapes").

To see for yourself, you can easily find videos and images of what happens to people who get hit by trucks online. I won't link them here, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Wow, nice answer. Somehow I feel like you would feel quite at home with some of the questions on our sister site [WorldBuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) Just leaving the link here in case you want to check out the site. Based on this answer questions like [How to safely check if you are immortal?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/94154/28789) or [What (modern) weapons could be used to destroy skeletal enemies as completely as possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/136083/28789) might be right up your alley :D